# Cannot embed custom fonts using vuejs2 and webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, fonts, vuejs2, webpack-2

I am trying to embed custom fonts within my website. I am using VueJS 2 and Webpack 2. I am new to both so forgive me if this is something really simple.

**My vuejs src structure:-**

```
  |---src
  |--assets
  |  |- fonts
  |  |--- 2E8332_1_0.eot
  |  |--- 2E8332_0_0.woff2
  |  |--- 2E8332_1_0.woff
  |  |--- 
  |--styles
  |  |- _fonts.scss
  |  |- _global.scss
```

**_fonts.scss:-**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HalisGR-Black'; 
  src: url('../assets/fonts/2E8332_1_0.eot'); 
  src: url('../assets/fonts/2E8332_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../assets/fonts/2E8332_1_0.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/2E8332_1_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../assets/fonts/2E8332_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

**_global.scss:-**

```css
@import 'src/assets/styles/_fonts.scss';

h1, h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'HalisGR-Black', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

**webpack.base.conf.js:-**

```js
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve(dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
            config.build.assetsPublicPath :
            config.dev.assetsPublicPath
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            '@': resolve('src')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                enforce: 'pre',
                include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
                options: {
                    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: vueLoaderConfig
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong because the font does not seem to load in the console I get this message as seen in this [image: screenshot of error]

I have tried different path names such as:

```
./src/assets/fonts/font_name
/assets/fonts/font_name
```

none seem to work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry this is solved it required ../src

Comment: Close the question then

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you've missed `assets` dir in path to your font files. 
I guess, after this change it should work:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HalisGR-Black'; 
  src: url('../assets/fonts/2E8332_1_0.eot'); 
  src: url('../assets/fonts/2E8332_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../assets/fonts/2E8332_1_0.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../assets/fonts/2E8332_1_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../assets/fonts/2E8332_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my original post. I get the same error